# Proof of a limit of a real function with rational paraphernalia

Tags: real-analysis

A real-valued function $f(x)$ of a real argument $x$ has a limit $A$ for $x=x_0$ . I prove this by choosing $\epsilon$, and showing that a number $\delta$ exists so that $\left|f(x) – A\right| < \epsilon$ if $\left|x-x_0\right|< \delta$. 
My question is now: if I only have access to rational values for $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, is my proof still valid edit: for all such functions f(x)?

Comment: Why would you only have access to rational values for $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?

Comment: Hint: for any positive real number $x$, there exists natural numbers $M,N$ such that $N < Mx < N+1$.

Comment: @Stahl Because when you are defining the reals using the rationals, that is all you have; rationals.

Comment: @ABC: we're starting with a real-valued function of a real argument, not a rational-valued function of a rational argument. As such, I assume that the reals have already been constructed or assumed to exist.

Comment: @Stahl That is incidental, as the nature of the argument of $f$ and the values it takes has little to do with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. All is important is that the domain and codomain of $f$ have an absolute value. This absolute value could even be taking values on the rationals.

Answer (score 1):

The key concept in an $\epsilon - \delta$ limit proof is that **given any** $\epsilon > 0$, **there exists** $\delta > 0$ such that $\left|f(x) - A\right| < \epsilon$ whenever $\left|x - x_0\right| < \delta$: we must be able to do this for any $\epsilon$, but notice that $\delta$ has no restrictions - we just need to find it. One can observe that if for a particular $\epsilon - \delta$ pair such that the inequalities hold, *any smaller $\delta'$ will also work for the same $\epsilon$*. Similarly, if we have an $\epsilon - \delta$ pair such that the inequalities hold, any larger $\epsilon'$ will work for the same $\delta$. We can use this and the density of the rational numbers to show that it suffices to prove that for all $\epsilon\in\Bbb Q^+$, there exists a $\delta$ such that the inequalities hold.

Suppose you know that for all $\epsilon\in\Bbb Q^+$ you can find a $\delta_{\epsilon}$ such that the inequalities hold. Now you want to show they hold for all irrational $r\in\Bbb R^+$ as well. Then let $r$ be an arbitrary positive irrational and choose a rational number $0 < q < r$, and use the $\delta_q$ for $q$ to say that $\left|f(x) - A\right| < q < r$ whenever $\left|x - x_0\right| < \delta_q$. So, if you show the inequality holds for positive rational $\epsilon$, you have actually shown it for all positive real $\epsilon$. Here we are using the fact that the rationals are [dense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) in the reals, and you can find many proofs of this online or in a basic real analysis text (also refer to Ian Coley's comment).

As for "only having access to" rational $\delta$ (and I cannot see why this would be the case), this is also not a problem: $\delta$ only needs to be found - it doesn't matter what it is!

Comment: Thanks, I see that now. I had some thoughts about problems with ”holes” in the proof for nonrational numbers. I see now that  it is the other way around, so that something about f(x) that is correct for rational x may not be correct for an extended function with real  arguments, for some of which f(x) may be unknown.